# How do I drop a file onto a perl script to parse it and write the output file to the same directory

Tags: perl, parsing, drag-and-drop, par

I have a working perl script that opens a imput file, parse it and then open a output file and write the parsed output to it. Now I want to be able to drop a file to be script. The file should be read and the written file should have the same name with a different extension and be stored in the same directory(!) where the file was dropped from. The script itself is converted to a exe using PAR:Packer. I'm using Windows 7 and the latest version Strawbery Perl (5.16.2)

The way I check for the file name is :

```
unless ($#ARGV == -1) {
    $filename = $ARGV[0];
}
```

This is how I open the input file :

```
open (my $mel, "<", $filename) or die "\nFile does not exist.\n";
```

And this is how I open the output file :

```
open (my $out, ">", 'majorEventLog.Prs') or die "Can't open output file: $!";
```

The issue I face is that the input file is not recognised at all. Second, what do I need to do to have the output file to be created in the same directory ? When I created a cmd file the input file worked but it stored the output file in my home directory. But I do not like to use the CMD, and I also would like to have the output file in the same directory than the input file. How do I need to change my code?

Comment: Does it die saying `File does not exist`? Also post the complete code, at least the part where you're writing in the filehandle (for output file).

Comment: There are other reasons an open operation could fail. It would be more informative to do: open $mel, '<', $filename or die "open $filename: $!";

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get input file name:

```
my $filename = shift;
die ("Please provide input file\n") unless defined $filename;
die ("$filename does not exist\n")  unless -f $filename;
```

Use this to generate output filename in the same directory:

```
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;

my ($name, $directory, $suffix) = fileparse($filename);
my $outfile = File::Spec->catfile($directory, "output.txt");
```